# Emacs gdb speedbar in same window

Tags: emacs, gdb, emacs-speedbar

I am using emacs gdb with gdb-many-windows mode,
I am noticing that the gdb watch expressions speedbar opens in a different window.

I want to have it in the same window. I looked into http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar which claimed to allow speedbar to open in the same window, i installed it and it works fine for the normal speedbar.

But how do  i get it to work with the gdb watch expressions speedbar,
is there any way i can get gdb watch expressions sppedbar to open in the same window by default (say as the 7th window in the GDB gui interface)?

Answer (score 0):

- C-x 2 (split any existing buffer into two)
- C-x b SPEEDBAR ( Switch to speed bar buffer)

Note: This worked for me in Emacs version 25.1